# Checking for IIS errors Http 500 errors in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I have a server core instance with IIS installed and I am getting some HTP 500 errors from some web services is their a way to get more details via PowerShell?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Please add more detail. Show your errors, your code, what you've tried to change or anything that could be relevant to this issue. As it stands right now, your question is not applicable for Stack Overflow and will be marked for closure.

Comment: You can also refer to this article about how to Capture Failed request tracing with Powershell. [This article](https://github.com/CJHarmath/iisseven/blob/master/Enable-IISTracing.ps1).

Answer (score 0):

IIS events/errors are stored in the event viewers application log. you can start the event log remote from another system via `mmc.exe -> Data -> Snap-In add/remove -> event viewer -> choose the remote computer -> finish`

or search with Powershell: `Get-EventLog -LogName application -source "*IIS*"`

Greetings